# Solr returns multiple (incorrect) values instead of one correct one

Tags: java, spring, indexing, solr, spell-checking

I have a `Spring MVC` project that `Solr` is connected to. Accordingly, a full-text search is implemented in the project, and since the project is in *Russian*, `SOLR` searches for information in *Russian* (for example: **Ivan** - Russian. "**Иван**"), and also if you enter a word in *Russian*, forgetting to switch the keyboard language **Bdfy** - "**Ivan**"(on the English layout of the Russian-English keyboard), in any case he gives the correct result - it gives out users with the name **Ivan**.

But the problem is that if there is a user with the name **Abdula** (in Russian letters), and in the search type in *Russian* - "**Абдула**", then he will display the only available **Абдула** for me, then the one written in *Russian* will translate into the English layout ("**Абдула**" - **F,lekf**) and then will return more users with part of the name that matches **F,lekf**.

How can this be fixed ...?

So that if he finds a user with the name **Abdula**, he does not go further to transform the data and display unnecessary...

[image]

```java
public <T extends Index> IndexQueryResult<T> query(IndexQuery<T> indexQuery) throws IndexException {
        Core core = getCore(indexQuery.getEntityClass());
        try {
            if (core == null)
                throw new SolrServerException("Solr core is not defined");

            SolrClient solr = solrConfiguration.getSolrClient(core);

            String selectQuery = indexQuery.getQuery() == null
                    ? "" : StringUtils.escapeCharacters(indexQuery.getQuery(), ESCAPE_CHARACTERS, '\\');
            String spellcheckSuggestion = null;
            if (indexQuery.isUseSpellcheck()) {
                SolrQuery spellSelect = new SolrQuery(selectQuery);
                spellSelect.setParam("spellcheck.q", selectQuery);
                spellSelect.setParam("spellcheck", "on");
                spellSelect.setRequestHandler("/spell");
                QueryResponse spellResponse = solr.query(spellSelect, SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
                if (spellResponse.getSpellCheckResponse() != null) {
                    spellcheckSuggestion = spellResponse.getSpellCheckResponse().getCollatedResult();
                }
            }

// Other method code ...

}
```

```xml
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text_spell</str>
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
<!--      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>-->
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">0</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">0</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

MyClassKeyboardLayoutFilter(for make (rus.**Ivan**)"**Иван**" -> "**Bdfy**").

```java
protected static final char[] LATINS = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']',
            'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', '\'', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v',
            'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '`'};

// ... other code

protected void incrementTokenLogic() {
        char[] buffer = charTermAttr.buffer();
        if (buffer.length > 0) {
            char[] newBuffer = new char[charTermAttr.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < charTermAttr.length(); i++) {
                char ch = buffer[i];
                if (LATIN_TO_CYR_MAP.containsKey(ch)) {
                    newBuffer[i] = LATIN_TO_CYR_MAP.get(ch);
                } else {
                    newBuffer[i] = CYR_TO_LATIN_MAP.getOrDefault(ch, ch);
                }
            }
            terms.add(newBuffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that problem is because `,` in "F,lekf"

Comment: Okey, maybe, and how I can fix it?

Comment: What is the definition of the field you're searching? What is the search result if you search with the given string in Solr's query interface?